# How can I pass a variable to children classes and change it in React?

Tags: reactjs

I wish to make a page with a toolbar at the top which determines which page the body displays. I set a variable called "pageActive" that is held in the state of the App class.

the parent is this.

```
   class App extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        this.state = {
            pageActive: 1,
        };

    }

    changePageActive = (newPage) => {
        this.setState( {pageActive: newPage});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <LeagueToolbar pageActive={this.state.pageActive}/>
                <LeagueBody pageActive={this.state.pageActive}
                            changePageActive={this.changePageActive}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and the child is this.

```
   class LeagueToolbar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            menuPosition: null,
        };

    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ menuPosition: event.currentTarget });
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.props.changePageActive(2); // does not work
        this.setState({ menuPosition: null });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="Menu"
                                    onClick={this.handleClick} >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Menu
                            id="simple-menu"
                            anchorEl={this.state.menuPosition}
                            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "left" }}
                            getContentAnchorEl={null}
                            keepMounted
                            open={Boolean(this.state.menuPosition)}
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                        >
                            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>League Summary</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>History</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Admin</MenuItem>
                        </Menu>

                        <Typography variant="h6" >
                            {(function(){
                                switch(this.props.pageActive) { // does not work
                                    case 1:
                                        return <div>option1</div>;
                                    case 2:
                                        return <div>option2</div>;
                                }
                            })}
                        </Typography>

                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LeagueToolbar;
```

So, I am passing the "pageActive" as a property to the child but I cannot read its value.
Also, I pass the function "changePageActive" and it is "not a function" when I run it.
I am only learning React and I must be missing something fundamental but all I could find is that the variable "pageActive" has to reside on the parent and so should the function that mutates it.

Comment: According to your code listing, your are passing the `changePageActive` prop to `LeagueBody` component but trying to use it in `LeagueToolbar`.

Comment: You are not passing the function `changePageActive` to `LeagueToolbar`. Also there is a problem with your switch in the render.

Comment: Thanks, I do not get the function error anymore, but I still cannot read the pageActive variable in the children classes

Answer (score 1):

Error is passing function-definition in JSX of `LeagueToolbar`, this is the solution:

```
getActivePage = () => {
        switch(this.props.pageActive) { 
            case 1:
                return <div>option1</div>;
            case 2:
                return <div>option2</div>;
            default: 
                return '';
    }

    <Typography variant="h6" >{this.getActivePage()}</Typography>
```

Comment: So, it is not possible to pass a variable? do you pass the get function ?

Answer (score 1):

First pass `changePageActive={this.changePageActive}` as props to `LeagueToolbar` Component

```
<LeagueToolbar pageActive={this.state.pageActive} changePageActive={this.changePageActive}/>
```

And you should also call the anonymous function i.e. using switch statement  in `render` method. Since you are only providing the function reference it will  not work.

Also use arrow function to bind `this`.

i.e.

```
{() => {
     switch(this.props.pageActive) { 
        case 1:
          return <div>option1</div>;
        case 2:
          return <div>option2</div>;
      }
}()} // calling the function
```

Answer (score 0):

The main bug is here:

```
<Typography variant="h6" >
    {(function(){
        switch(this.props.pageActive) { // does not work
            case 1:
                return <div>option1</div>;
            case 2:
                return <div>option2</div>;
        }
    })}
</Typography>
```

You declare anonymous function `(function() {.....})` but you did not call it. Just add and additiona round brackets at the end - `(function() {.....}())` or as @avinash-mahlawat proposed - move this code into separate class method. This will make you code more readable.

And don't forget to pass changePageActive to LeagueToolbar

```
<LeagueToolbar pageActive={this.state.pageActive} changePageActive={this.changePageActive}/>
```